# Do Visual Studio project templates exist for Open Scene Graph?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, openscenegraph

I'm learning OSG and would like know if project templates exist. Without a template I'm forced to add the linkers and libraries every time that I want make a new project in Visual Studio.

Is there a way I can create a template?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio templates are one of the available CMake targets - you have to get CMake for Windows and point it to your OSG folder.  It's a bit of work to go through the steps of a CMake build just to get the VS files, so I usually just stick with one version for a while once I've built it.  I found some decent instructions online:

http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/building-openscenegraph-3-0-0-from-source-for-both-x86-and-x64/

They're a couple years old, but still valid.  Note that he's using VS2010, which is version 10, if you're using VS2008 still, it's version 9.

You could also try just downloading the pre-built binaries from AlphaPixel, although I'm not sure if they include any of the Solution/Project files in their distributions:

http://openscenegraph.alphapixel.com/osg/downloads/free-openscenegraph-binary-downloads